# svn update for different users

Tags: svn

How can I setup the permissions in Linux so that two users can update the same SVN and users are addeed in same group?

**P.S.** yes i did that ..but not working still two different users cant update svn. I have two users user 1 and user2 for same project webip and i checkout project from svn server to dev machine. From there i have diffrent user who commit code on svn server daily and do svn update from dere login not root (dev server) .but it shows error as ./svn/tmp/enries permission denied. and i read that answer and changed directory permisons as chmod g+s wepip but still same issue .User who is owner of directory can update other i hve to change owner everytime for one user

Comment: Is there a reason that they cannot work in their own directories?

Comment: they are updating dere code  on dev server from dere ssh login like  user1@53.36.83.25$ svnupadte and user2@53.36.83.25 svn update   to same project on dev server when user1 update his code he get the onership of file and when user 2 tries to update he get permission denied error

Comment: Read what is setgid bit and how to use it. Why two users can't have separated WC?